# Clicking next on last slide ends slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I've been working on my first slider using javascript/jquery and the slider itself is working except when I'm on my last image if I click next it goes to a blank space and stops. If I just let it fun it loops fine on its own and goes back to the first slide. I've tried making a JSFiddle, but for some reason I can't get it to work at all in fiddle so their may be something wrong with the starting process, I'm not sure. It works fine on my local site other than the problem of no longer working if I click the next button while it's on the last slide.

HTML5

```
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="slider">
            <img id="1" src="Images/slide_image1.jpg" alt="HDTV">
            <img id="2" src="Images/slide_image2.jpg" alt="Furniture">
            <img id="3" src="Images/slide_image3.jpg" alt="Electronics">
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="left" onclick="prev(); return false;">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="right" onclick="next(); return false;">Next</a>
    </div>

    <script src="JS/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/slider.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS3

```
.wrapper {
    width: 990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider{
    width: 990px;
    height: 270px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

#slider > img {
    width: 990px;
    height: 270px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}

a.left {
    float: left;
}

a.right {
    float: right;
}
```

JavaScript

```
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider > img#1').fadeIn(300)
    startSlider();
});

function startSlider(){
    count = $('#slider > img').size();

    loop = setInterval(function(){

        if(sliderNext > count){
            sliderNext = 1;
            sliderInt = 1;
        }

        $('#slider > img').fadeOut(300);
        $('#slider > img#' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

        sliderInt = sliderNext;
        sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

    }, 3000)
}

function prev() {
    newSlide = sliderInt - 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}

function next() {
    newSlide = sliderInt + 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}

function stopLoop() {
    window.clearInterval(loop);
}

function showSlide(Id) {
    stopLoop();
    if(Id > count){
            sliderNext = 1;
            sliderInt = 1;
        }

        else if(Id < 1){
            Id = count;
        }

        $('#slider > img').fadeOut(300);
        $('#slider >img#' + Id).fadeIn(300);

        sliderInt = Id;
        sliderNext = Id + 1;
        startSlider();
}

$('#slider > img').hover(
    function() {
        stopLoop();
    },
    function(){
        startSlider();
    }
);
```

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5MrH/) for your code.

Comment: Oh thanks, I can't usually get that to work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the if-else statement in the `showSlide()` funciton. It should be:

```
if (Id > count) {
    Id = 1;
} else if (Id < 1) {
    Id = count;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5MrH/1/)

BTW: I think you could simplify your HTML and JQuery code like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7M6Mb/)

Comment: Yup that was the problem and that's a really cool trick you showed for simplifying my HTML and JQuery. I'm kind of a new at web development so I'm trying to learn how to write shorter and more effective code. Specifically on the HTML side of things, there just doesn't seem to be a lot of information out there on better HTML coding.

Comment: I didn't explain anything in the "simplified" jsfiddle. If you have any questions regarding that code, just leave a comment on this answer.